# realtime database of firebase no showing data(showing null)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

app is running fine...just data is not appearing...
i have added sha
user email is shown after login and in login activity i have added

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aj").child("name").setValue("aditya");
```

but in realtime database data is not shown
just in case ..i also waited for like half an hour after trying all things..network is also good.
database
[picture of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGFEc.png)
rules in database
earlier it was

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1625337000000",  // 2021-7-4
    ".write": "now < 1625337000000",  // 2021-7-4
  }
}
```

i read that it should be true
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-save-data-to-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-android/  so now
[rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYAWg.png)

and also
[added_firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFYh4.png)
giving error on initialising

```
 FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

android studio wants to change type of mDataBase like this and it does not give error now

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

app gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebase0"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

MainActivity.java
// not working for single child i.e FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aj").child("name").setValue("aditya");
and nor for map
.....searched it...tried incognito  mode, different browsers,devices...still "null " in database

```
package com.example.firebase0;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button logout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logout= findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
//        FirebaseDatabase  mDatabase;
//        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"logged out successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
            }
        });

        //FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aj").child("name").setValue("aditya");
        //yha aj branch ka name child hai uski value aditya
        // agr ek branch ke ek se jada child bnane to hashmap
//        DatabaseReference mDatabase;
//        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        HashMap<String , Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name","aj");
        map.put("sirname","jain");
        map.put("desh","bharat");

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aj_database").child("multiple_children").setValue(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Posted are Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Posted are Failed\n"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `updateChildren()` method and try to use the `setValue()` method

Comment: @GSepetadelis no sir still not showing

Comment: it worked...the error was the comma after second true in rules of realtime database

Answer (score 0):

Add onSuccessListener to know about write was done or not.

```
 HashMap<String , Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name","aj");
        map.put("sirname","jain");
        map.put("desh","bharat");

mDatabase.child("aj database").child("multiple children").setValue(map)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Write was successful!
                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                // ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: @androidLearer sir i edited the ques....giving error on initailising mDataBase...pls see attached image

Comment: i have added toast ...not getting any toast messages neither of success...nor of failure...here might be some problem i think

Comment: sir..pls help here getting no taosts and also not able to initialize mDatabase  as FirebaseDatabase  mDatabase;

Comment: Try to set value for single child node to check whether it is working or not.like  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aj_database").setValue()@AdityaJain

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aj database").child("multiple children").setValue(map);`

more about [follow this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-save-data-to-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-android/)

Comment: can't understand what u want to say...i have done same thing right??

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User {  // Create user-class 
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String desh;
    
    public User {}
    
    public User(String name, String surname, String desh) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.desh = desh;
    }
    
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("surname", surname);
        result.put("desh", desh);
        return result;
    }
    
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...
    FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        // ...

        writeNewUser("aj", "jain", "bharat");

    }
    
    // method to save new user
    private void writeNewUser(String name, String surname, String desh) {
        String userKey = mDatabase.child("users").push().getKey(); // a unique user key
        User user = new User(name, surname, desh);
        Map<String, Object> userValues = user.toMap();
        mDatabase.updateChildren(new HashMap<String, Object>().put("/users/" + userKey, userValues));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: sir i edited the ques....giving error on initailising mDataBase...pls see attached image –

Answer (score 0):

be sure you linked between Firebase and Your App how.
How can_do_that?
from toolbar, Android Studio Choose Tools and FireBase and in right screen you will show the dialog and choose Realtime database and follow Step 1,2 ...now your app is ready to use firebase

```html
 HashMap<String , Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name","aj");
        map.put("sirname","jain");
map.put("desh","bharat");

//prefer put "aj_database" no "aj database"

mDatabase.child("aj_database").child("multiple_children").setValue(map)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.maketext(this,"Posted are Success",Toast.LONG);
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.maketext(this,"Posted are Failed\n"+e,Toast.LONG);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes sir i have edited que and added image...firebase is added

Comment: i am not getting any toast sir....here might be some problem @Mohsen sir

Answer (score 0):

it worked after  i removed the comma after true on second line of rules of realtime database

Answer (score 0):

Unless your database location is `us-central1`, you must pass the database URL to `getInstance()`. Only then did it work for me, because I used to have the same problem!